# set of Cauchy sequences complete matrix

Tags: cauchy-sequences

Given a set S, let S* be the set of all Cauchy sequences. Is it true that S* is a complete metric space?

Suppose that $A, B \in S^*$. Then the metric is $\rho(A,B) = \lim_{v \to \infty} \rho(a_{v},b_{v})$.

Comment: In what metric?

Comment: Suppose that $A, B \in S^*$. Then the metric is $\rho(A,B) = \lim_{v \to \infty} \rho(a_{v},b_{v})$.

Comment: The proposed metric is not a metric, because it can assign "distance" 0 to a pair of distinct sequences.

Comment: It allows S* to be a pseudometric, we can define S** to be a set consisting of equivalence classes of metrics so that $A\asymp B$ if $\rho (A,B) = 0$. Then S** will be a metric.